# Do fragments keep running even if not on screen?

Tags: java, android

I have a Android app that shows lots of real-time data jammed onto one large scrolling activity.

Now i want to split it up into two simpler screens using fragments, where only one fragment may be on the screen at any one time.

I read up a whole lot on fragments and watched several videos, but before i start ripping up my code to convert it to fragments i wanted to know the following.

If i create two fragments A and B, then while showing fragment B, data comes in for fragment A. Can the controlling activity still communicate with fragment A giving it data even though its off screen? OR do i have to save the data somewhere and then when the user switches to fragment A then I give fragment A the data to be shown, while saving incoming data for fragment B which will now be off screen?

The problem is that right now im not saving any data because everything is on one screen, so as data come in i just displayed it, but if i switch to using fragments i dont know if i can do the same thing by passing the data to the fragments even if they are not on screen at the same time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve your data with multiple asynchronous requests in your Activity, you may create a fragment for each of them and move related retrieval operation into that fragment (probably to `oncreateView()` method). Then, you can use ViewPager (probably with TabLayout) in the parent Activity to be able to use all those fragments. Therefore, your Activity only deals with setting the ViewPager and leave the rest to fragments.

ViewPager shows one page at a time but it can initialize other fragments as well, even before they are shown. You can use ViewPager's `setOffscreenPageLimit()` method to increase that range.

In case you need a communication channel between fragments and the activity, you may create callback mechanisms, as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).